# How to start a command with subprocess with output in some file, unblocked?

Tags: python

I am trying to use `subprocess` to start a command on the command-line for which I want to have the output written into some file. So, in other words, I want to have e.g. the following command executed within python:

```
python my_code.py --arg1 > output.txt
```

I tried the following:

```
import subprocess
cwd = "/home/path/to/the/executable"
cmd = "python my_code.py --arg1"
with open('output.txt', "w") as outfile:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=outfile, cwd = cwd)
```

but the output file stayed empty. How to else do it (not blocking!)?

Addition:

My guess is that the output file is created, but is being closed as soon as the above code finishes. Therefore, no output to that file...

Comment: what's `my_code.py`?

Comment: Its a python script (a service) which I want to start from another piece of code. Its just some code, does not matter...

Comment: `subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=outfile, cwd = cwd).wait()`

Comment: I am looking for a NON-BLOCKING way to do this. I do not want to wait until the call of `my_code.py` has finished. I want the above code snippet to end as soon as it has finished...

Comment: I found something interesting while searching about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329648/unable-to-write-to-stdin-in-subprocess

Comment: @SvenMarnach - closing the file in the parent doesn't affect the file in the child.

Comment: This should work, at least on linux. The subprocess will continue execution and write to the file. Does your parent script exit immediately? Do you see the program using, say, `ps x`? Could it have failed?

Comment: `cmd.split()` is sensitive to things like spaces in command parameters. `shlex.split(cmd)` may be a better option.

Comment: If the main process ends before child, the child keeps running. The child should flush its stdout as soon as it writes to see the output in the file

Comment: @NizamMohamed is correct. The child writes to `stdout` but it only appears in the output file when a full (system dependent) block is written or when the child exits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys.stdout` is buffered by default. You can disable it by passing `-u` to `python`.

```
import subprocess
cwd = "/home/path/to/the/executable"
cmd = "python -u my_code.py --arg1"
with open('output.txt', "w") as outfile:
    subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=outfile, cwd = cwd)
```

Comment: This is a great answer but is only needed if you want "real time" updates of the file. The system purposely delays file writes as it is more efficient.